# How can I find string ending with `\n` in coccinelle

Tags: c, coccinelle

I have a macro in C, say `LOG()`, which prints given string.  The macro adds `"\n"` at the end.  Because of this, if we have `LOG("hello\n")`, the new line is redundant.

How can I find such macro with newline at the end with [coccinelle](https://coccinelle.gitlabpages.inria.fr/website/) and remove it?

BTW, `LOG()` takes format and args just like `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully found strings ending with `\n` with the following coccinelle script.

```
@r@
expression E =~ ".*\\n";
@@
LOG(E, ...);

@script:python@
re << r.E;
@@
print(f"{re}")
```